# Best JavaScript editable grids/ tables for table row count of around 1000+

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsp

I searched some of the questions asked on best JavaScript or jQuery grids but I could not find what I need so posting this... If this is asked before please paste the link to it. Thanks!

My requirements:

1. I am searching for a JavaScript (jquery preferable) editable tables where a user can use tab (like in excel) to move from one cell to another in a row. Most of the grids I looked - a user has to click on each cell.
2. A user will be updating multiple columns and rows and data should be updated in db.
3. This is more of a suggestion than a requirement- is it good practice to load 1000 rows and is the grids capable of handling it?

My background code will be in jsp/HTML and java/servlets

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you had a look at [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki)? , checkout this [example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html)

Comment: in my opinion this is the best grid available http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: SlickGrid is going off support for a while. Have you checked ShieldUI's editable grid: http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/editing-restful-web-service?

Comment: So annoyed that whenever someone develops a javascript Grid plugin, they assume you want a spreadsheet with column headers.  Yeah, i want editable cells, but if I wanted headers I would search for Spreadsheet plugins.

Comment: Here is another jquery plugin.
http://www.bossanova.uk/jexcel/tracking-changes-on-the-spreadsheet

Comment: I found this website that make a good comparison from different components: https://jspreadsheets.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should definitely have a look at [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki), it is flexible, and offers all your requirements.
The best part is it is dead easy to use.

Checkout these [examples](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples).

Answer (score 4):

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

jqgrid is a very good plugin to use

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid).

It is JavaScript grid/table/spreadsheet UI component built on JQuery. It supports editing, and  we use it to load over 1000+ rows of data easily.

Have a look at the [Spreadsheet](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-spreadsheet.html) example for ideas.